# Creating an Indented menu in quicklaunch, can be seen based on permission-sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to create an Indented quicklaunch menu in sharepoint 2013 that can be seen only by particular groups, based on permissions. An example of this would be:

```
Admin
  Example
  Example
User
  Example
  Examples
```

For example, A user who is in a group that has full control can see both "Admin" and "User" and the subheadings while a user who is in a group "read" can only see "User" and it's subheadings. I've tried using the navigation from the site settings however can't seem to find a way.